# Upload file with paperclip and angularjs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm trying to implement this Angularjs upload in my rails application:

**[Angular File upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)**

This is my photos_controller:

```
def create
@photo = current_user.photos.new(photo_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @photo.save
    format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @photo }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def photo_params
  params.require(:photo).permit(:album_id, :user_id, :title, :description, :path)
end
```

---

I think that I'm close of the solution. When I try to upload I get this error:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: photo

Extracted source (around line #92):
9091929394          
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def photo_params
  params.require(:photo).permit(:album_id, :user_id, :title, :description, :path)
end
 end
```

I think that I need to format the data send to a format like this, isn't?

```
{"photo"=>{"tmpname"=>"253", "etc"=>"1"}}
```

The terminal log:

[image: terminal log]

my html input:

```
<input type="file" nv-file-select="" name="photo[path]" id="photo_path" uploader="uploader" multiple  /><br/>
```

My column with paper clip is `path`

I'm not getting how I do this in this angular script.

Comment: can you post your photo_params method and logs when you submit your from?

Comment: I wanted your logs from terminal not header logs :). Also post your form i think your params are not correctly formed

Comment: My form is exctly the same of the demo of angular script

Comment: In my terminal it's do a POST to localhost/photos/upload with the params that is in de question

Comment: Can you post your form and your logs. I can't see your params in question. I'm insisting on posting your code because there may be some error in your form so just want to see it :)

Comment: edited with the terminal log and html input!! Thanks!!

Comment: you just have a input? no form?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to comment yet but usually this error comes from a naming issue, make sure your fields are named following the rails convention for example "photo[path]"

Comment: I would check to see what params are being received on your local server as Mandeep suggested above, it should say in your terminal logs. I still believe its a naming error. It looks like your form is being submitted asynchronously by the Angular module, I don't know how your providing the param name but it seems like this should be done in js and not through an input field attribute. To be honest I know very little about angular but it seems like this should be an option when you set up your uploader.